# Removing the word "chapter" from the title

Tags: roman-numerals

I'm learning Latex and I want to know if it's possible to set just a roman numeral at the beginning of each chapter. I mean, Just type:

```
\chapter{}
```

and the result must be: I, II, III,IV,V at the beginning of each chapter. I tried:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

but I'm getting "Chapter I",  "Chapter II", so I want to remove the word "Chapter" from the title and also from the TOC.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. (The class you use might impact the answer.)

Answer (score 2):

If you use KOMA-script and if you understand German, you can find an answer here: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3046/wie-kann-ich-mit-koma-script-das-kapitel-prafix-andern

The following might be roughly what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{% 
\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter%
\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

Some text

\chapter{}

More Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Forget this solution. The next one is much better!

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to eliminate `Chapter`

```
\documentclass[%
  chapterprefix=false % no "chapter" in title
]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
\end{document}
```